# Current-current correlator in superconductivity

Tags: resource-recommendations, superconductivity, correlation-functions

I was reading a paper on superconductivity. There is a claim that if the momentum space current-current correlation function $\langle\mathcal{T} j_{\mu}(k)j_{\nu}(-k) \rangle$ has a pole at zero momentum, then superconductivity occurs. I feel this might have something to do with linear response. Could anyone provide any reference on this?

Comment: A pole in a response function means the system has a long lived state with those characteristics. In this case, if at k=0 you have long lived current,  then you are simply stating that the system can support uniform current indefinitely (i.e. superconductivity)